# OpenVPN Bad LZO decompression header byte: 69

Tags: linux, vpn, android, openvpn, compression

On  Arch Linux I run OpenVPN 2.3.9 server and I get this error **"Bad LZO decompression header byte: 69"**

I run the client on a rooted Motorola XT1039 android lollipop 5.1 and I use official "OpenVPN Connect" android app to connect: I get this error Tun write error: write_some: invalid argument

client configuration: http://pastebin.com/kR3EGj1d

Server configuration http://pastebin.com/c9nhX6Lv

Comment: Server log file verbosity level 9: http://pastebin.com/2jm7KRiU

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that your server has `comp-lzo adaptive` in the config, but the client does not have compression enabled at all.  So the client is sending uncompressed packets, while the server is expecting a compression header.  Add `comp-lzo` to your client config file (`adaptive` is the default mode for `comp-lzo`, so you can omit that).